# Keep TabBar when moving to another view controller

Tags: ios, swift

I have a storyboard like this

-> NavigationController -> LoginView -> TabBarController -> VC1 -> VC2

I didn't manage to make a "move" from VC1 to VC2 keeping the tab bar.

I tried the followings :

- Segue (Show type)

  ```
  self.performSegueWithIdentifier("toVC2segue", sender: self)
  ```
- instantiate programmaticaly :

  ```
  // prepare for future display
  let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
  let navigationVC = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController as! UINavigationController

  // prepare next view
  let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("VC2id")

  self.tabBarController?.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
  ```

but both make the tab bar disappearing.

I tried also

```
self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = false
```

but this didn't change anything.

Do you have another idea ?

PS : I updated my scheme above...

Edit : After reading the answers below, I tried to add another navigation controller :

-> NavigationController -> LoginView -> TabBarController -> NavigationController -> VC1 -> VC2

but I have now 2 navigation bars superposed in VC1 and VC2...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to set TabBarContoller as rootViewController of the app. So scheme should be as follow:

> TabBarContoller -> Tab1 -> UINavigationController -> ViewContoller1 ->
>   ViewContoller2.

In such case you can navigate between ViewContoller1 and ViewContoller2 and TabBarContoller will remain visible.

Comment: so, each tab should have its own navigation controller ?

Comment: Each tab should have its own navigation controller or view controller. Depend on use case.

Comment: @NahoumCohen No you don't, just connect the tab bar to each vc you want to have in the tab bar, select each vc and do: Editor > Embed In > Navigation Controller

Comment: Thanks dzk, but what is a bit complicated is that I customized my navigation bar for the whole application, and now I have to duplicate it and verify all the possible bugs...

Comment: After one hour spent on this problem, I think to give up... I updated my question

Comment: @salabaha Can we show tabbar in the scenario mentioned in question i.e. In UINavigationController -> TabBarContoller -> VC1 -> VC2 how can we show tabbar in VC2. As I need to have a common custom navigation bar and don't want to set navbar items separately in multiple times for each child VC's.

Comment: Even It needs an effort, you are in a right way. It should be done as in the answer.

Answer (score 7):

Your view hierarchy should not look like this if you want to keep the tabBar.

> -> NavigationController -> TabBarController -> VC1 -> VC2

You should change it to -> TabBarController -> NavigationController -> VC1 -> VC2

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to make sure that your VC1 to VC2 segue is in type `(Show e.g. Push)`. Then you need to make sure that VC1 is embedded in a `UINavigationController`
[image]

Answer (score 0):

> NavigationController->TabBarController->NavigationController->First
>   View->Button
>   Tapped->FirstDetailsViewController.storyboard(NavigationController
>   check Is intital View Controller)

[image]