# Navigate from a navigation bar view controller to a tab bar view controller

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

What is wrong with this approach? There is no coding behind it. But, I cannot see the item nor the title of the last scene on the right (as their titles are set to "cannot see").

Even if I add a back button, and set it's title to something, it keeps showing the default back button.

[The storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/adAJQ.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are pushing UITabBarViewController instance in to UINavigationViewController stack. In such case navigation bar is managed by UINavigationController that is way you don't see "Cannot see" UIBarButtonItem in the nav bar.

UITabBarViewController works best if it is the rootViewController of the application. Take a look at this [unswear](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35255010/4525866) to see how UITabBarViewController should be used.