# Push view controller not appearing below tab bar controller

Tags: swift

I have embed the login screen to navigation controller and i use only push method to go to another view when user logs in and all.
When the user press login button, the tab bar controller containing 4 tabs are pushed and viewed.
Default screen is named home which contains two buttons inside the view.
When the user press each button,it should take the user to another view controller without hiding the tab bar below,and it should be the same looking tab bar (my tab bar is transparent).

Problem here is when ever i press the button,Entire view is changed which means the new view controller is presented over top of the tab bar.

I am confused about the navigation controller stuff.
Is there any requirement for any connection between view controllers since i am using push method.I am not using segue from storyboard.
Everything is programatic.

Please help me to fix this out.

Comment: Edit your question with the code, you have used for pushing to TabBarController and the code for pushing from homeViewController to someOtherViewController. That will be helpful to understand the question.

Comment: The same conventional code used to push view controllers through navigation controller.

Comment: Self.navigatoionController?.pushViewController(view,animated:false)

Comment: I think you want to do the same than https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35254744/keep-tabbar-when-moving-to-another-view-controller so it would be a duplicated question

Comment: It didnt fixed...aren't you capable to find a solution for me?

Comment: That question is not exactly.the same as mine

Answer (score 0):

It happens when you push your `viewController` into your `navigationController` or present your `viewController` modally. You should just change your `tabbarController`'s `seletedIndex` when you tap the button.

```
tabBarController.selectedIndex = #index of your controller#
```