# Showing tab bar items in another view controller that is not in tab bar

Tags: swift, xcode, uitabbarcontroller

I am kinda new to swift and Xcode. 
I have a tab bar with four tabs. These four tab views has buttons to show other view controllers and I want to show the tab bar in those view controllers without adding them into the tab bar. 
But I googled but I couldn't find enough info. 
So I need help doing that.
Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keep TabBar when moving to another view controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35254744/keep-tabbar-when-moving-to-another-view-controller)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set TabBarContoller as rootViewController of the app. So scheme should be as follow:

> TabBarContoller -> Tab1 -> UINavigationController -> ViewContoller1 ->
>   ViewContoller2.

In such case you can navigate between ViewContoller1 and ViewContoller2 and TabBarContoller will remain visible.

Comment: I solved the problem. My navigation controllers was not proper, so once I removed them, problem solved. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so what you can do is , Imagine you have a Base UIViewController which has a tabbar at the bottom of the screen.

Add UIView above Tabbar. This UIView Will be a container for the UIViewControllers which will be shown when you tap on TabBar items. So When you tap on Tabbar item just Populate that View with specific UIViewController.